# taking value from google assistant

Tags: html, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

i dont know if this is right place to ask this question but i have looked everywhere dont know how to, so now going to my question, i have successfully installed google assistant on my laptop (windows 10) its working on cmd, i want to take google assistant answers into if-else, for example i ask google assistant go to my website, then what ever answer it gives me i want to use that inside if-else, for example if google assistant says this'...' then open website, mainly with javascript.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The right way to handle custom actions from the Assistant is [custom device actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview), which will allow you to extend the Assistant in order to add new functionality.

You can create [an action package](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/custom-actions) that accepts "go to my website" or several other possible queries. Then your sample code will receive an *action* with a user-defined key, like "action.WEBSITE". You can handle this logic specifically, and you'll also be able to add parameters if you want.

Comment: couldly kindly give me one example so i could modify it, for example ''open my website'' and it should open stackoverflow site

Comment: There's an example here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/custom-actions